# Custom post type with parent page? Possible?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting, urls

I'm having trouble getting my url structure the way I want.

I have a page with two sections:

- private
- company

Let's take private as an example. In this area, I wan't to have a url structure like this:

> private/customerservice/faq

Where private is the front page, /customerservice a sub-page of that, and /faq is a subpage of /customerservice. I want a my custom post type posts called FAQ to end up at private/customerservice/faq/%postname%.

Can this be done? And if not what are my options to get something similar?

In my CPT code right now I have:

```
$rewrite = array(
    'slug'                => 'private/customerservice/faq',
    'with_front'          => true,
    'pages'               => true,
    'feeds'               => true,
);
```

This will render my CPT post at the desired location, but private/customerservice/faq returns 404. privat/customerservice/ returns 404 aswell, or as expected the archive if I have set has_archive to true.

Any ideas about what I can do?

Comment: it should be possible. is your post type non-hierarchical? I'm also fairly certain you don't want `with_front` to be `true`, though in this case it probably wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: No it's hierachical. Should it not be? Even if it's hierarchical, I can't set a page to be my CPT parent or can I?

Comment: Surely this problem must be something other people have come across?